# Merge is duplicating rows in r

Tags: r, database, dataframe, merge

I have two data sets with country names in common.

[first data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDVOF.png)

As you can see, both data sets have a two letter country code formated the same way.

After running this code:
    merged<- merge(aggdata, Trade, by="Group.1" , all.y = TRUE, all.x=TRUE)

[I get the following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbgl9.png)

Rather than having 2 rows with the same country code, I'd like them to be combine.

Thanks!

Comment: good topic, but a terrible way of asking questions

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect that the Group.1 strings in one or other of your data frames has one or more trailing spaces, so they appear identical when viewed, but are not.  An easy way of visually checking whether they are the same:

```
levels(as.factor(Trade$Group.1))
levels(as.factor(aggdata$Group.1))
```

If the problem does turn out to be trailing spaces, then if you are using R 3.2.0 or higher, try:

```
Trade$Group.1 <- trimws(Trade$Group.1)
aggdata$Group.1 <- trimws(aggdata$Group.1)
```

Even better, if you are using `read.table` etc. to input your data, then use the parameter `strip.white=TRUE`

For future reference, it would be better to post at least a sample of your data rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
aggdata <- data.frame(Group.1 = c('AT', 'BE'), CASEID = c(1587.6551, 506.5), ISOCNTRY = c(NA, NA),
                      QC17_2 = c(2.0, 1.972332), D70 = c(1.787440, 1.800395))

Trade <- data.frame(Group.1 = c('AT', 'BE'), trade = c(99.77201, 100.10685))

merged<- merge(aggdata, Trade, by="Group.1" , all.y = TRUE, all.x=TRUE)
```

I had to transcribe your data by hand from your screenshots, so I only did the first two rows. If you could paste in a full sample of your data, that would be helpful. See here for some guidelines on producing a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/236541